# How to hide open VPN traffic from internet service provider

Tags: vpn

I wish to hide my open VPN traffic from my ISP. Current thoughts are using open VPN on port 443 https and using `shadowsocks proxy`. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot hide your traffic from your ISP. All of your TCP/IP packets are sent to your ISP first.

You can hide the contents of the packets via encryption, and even the IP addresses by using Tor.

However, the word salad you present ("using open vpn on port 443 https and using shadowsocks proxy") isn't going to do it. Also, it suggests that you need to do some more reading and thinking. What are you trying to do? Does networking work that way?

Do a Threat-Risk Analysys (I'm sure you can make this more complete):

What's the threat?

1. ISP will count my traffic.
2. ISP will know what sites I'm talking to.
3. ISP will know what I'm saying to those sites.

What are the risks?

1. ISP will bill for ALL the traffic.
2. ISP will tell some other entity what I'm doing online.

Only then will you be able to plan what you want to do.

Comment: don forget that in case of vpn use, all threats can be applied to vpn provider...